# Why does clojure's group-by not always maintain order?

Tags: clojure, group-by

Why does (group-by identity (range 1 50)) return results like

{32 [32], 1 [1], 33 [33], 2 [2], 34 [34], 3 [3], 35 [35]...

Is it multi-threading related? Is there any way around it?

...and does it break it's contract?

> Returns a map of the elements of coll keyed by the result of f on each element. The value at each key will be a vector of the corresponding elements, **in the order they appeared in coll**.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try entering `(type (group-by identity (range 1 50)))` in your REPL. You can see that the result is actually a hash map (of class `clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap`). This means that it's unordered: in principle the REPL could output the printed map literal in any order of key/value pairs.

The actual reason why it's printed the way it's printed has to do with Clojure's implementation of a hash map -- in terms of data structures, it's actually a wide tree where each node can have up to 32 children (hence the initial 32 in your output; recall that Clojure vectors and maps are often cited to have lookup cost of O(log32N)). [This blog article](http://blog.higher-order.net/2009/09/08/understanding-clojures-persistenthashmap-deftwice/) has a good summary.

And no, it doesn't violate the contract of `group-by`. The contract only specifies the ordering of the map's values' elements, not the ordering of the map *per se*.

Comment: <sigh> The "the value at each key" part seems so obvious now! ;) And I was wondering about the 32 as well but I thought there were enough Qs in there. Thanks.